# Enveloping cone of an ellipsoid with vertex $P$ has parabolic sections by plane $z=0$. Locus of $P$?

Tags: geometry, ellipsoids

The section of the enveloping cone of the ellipsoid whose vertex is $P$, by the plane $z=0$ is a parabola. Find the locus of $P$.

The given ellipsoid is $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{c^2}=1$
And the vertex be $P(x_1,y_1,z_1)$
Therefore equation of enveloping cone of $P$ to this ellipsoid is $SS_1=T^2$.
That is,
$$
\left(
  \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}-1
\right)
\left(
  \frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_1^2}{b^2}+\frac{z_1^2}{c^2}-1
\right)=
\left( \frac{xx_1}{a^2}+\frac{yy_1}{b^2}+\frac{zz_1}{c^2}-1
\right)^2$$

This meets the plane $z=0$ then

$$
\left(
  \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-1
\right)
\left(
  \frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_1^2}{b^2}+\frac{z_1^2}{c^2}-1
\right)=
\left(
  \frac{xx_1}{a^2}+\frac{yy_1}{b^2}-1
\right)^2$$

I don't know after this some one plz help.

Comment: Recall the relationship that the cone and plane must have for the section to be a parabola.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the conic as

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  x & y & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{1}{a^2}
  \left( \frac{y_1^2}{b^2}+\frac{z_1^2}{c^2}-1 \right) &
  -\frac{x_1 y_1}{a^2 b^2} &
  \frac{x_1}{a^2} \\
  -\frac{x_1 y_1}{a^2 b^2} &
  \frac{1}{b^2}
  \left( \frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{z_1^2}{c^2}-1 \right) &
  \frac{y_1}{b^2} \\
  \frac{x_1}{a^2} &
  \frac{y_1}{b^2} &
  -\frac{x_1^2}{a^2}-\frac{y_1^2}{b^2}-\frac{z_1^2}{c^2}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\ y \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}=0$$

For parabola,

$$\det
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{1}{a^2}
  \left( \frac{y_1^2}{b^2}+\frac{z_1^2}{c^2}-1 \right) &
  -\frac{x_1 y_1}{a^2 b^2} \\
  -\frac{x_1 y_1}{a^2 b^2} &
  \frac{1}{b^2}
  \left( \frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{z_1^2}{c^2}-1 \right)
\end{pmatrix}
=0$$

The equation for $P$ is

$$
\frac{1}{a^2b^2}
\left( \frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}-1 \right)
\left( \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}-1 \right)-
\left( \frac{xy}{a^2 b^2} \right)^2=0$$

$$\frac{(z^2-c^2)}{a^2 b^2 c^2}
\left( \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}-1 \right)
=0$$

$$\fbox{$z^2=c^2$}$$

providing $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}>0$.

Comment: I just posted a geometrical solution. A very tiny detail in the last sentence: "providing" $\to$ "provided".

Comment: @Ng Chung Tak How did you conclude that for a parabola that determinant should be zero?

Comment: @Franklin Please refer to **Matrix notation** and **Discriminant** under **General Cartesian form** 
 of **Conic Section** [*here*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form).

Comment: @NgChungTak That was truly a great enlightenment I had. Thank you!  Just one more thing : how did you obtain from $\frac{(z^2-c^2)}{a^2 b^2 c^2} \left( \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}-1 \right) =0$ **only $z^2=c^2$ is possible**. Is it because $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2=1$, isn't possible ? **If so,why ?**

Comment: That's usual trick of switching dummy variables in coordinate geometry.  $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ satisfies $\det \ldots =0$ which is just the equation of $P$.  Finally, the **radiant point** of the cone should be **outside the ellipsoid**.

Comment: @NgChungTak Thank you! So the real point is that **since $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is the vertex of the considered cone and hence can't lie on the ellipsoid, right?**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a geometric derivation of the fact that the locus is the two planes with equations

$$z=c \ \ \text{and} \ \ z=-c\tag{1}$$

confirming the result found by @Ng Chung Tak.

Let it be clear (this is implicit in the solution attempt of the OP) that we consider an ellipsoid whose axes are the coordinate axes in a Euclidean setting.

Indeed, a necessary condition for the fact that the intersection of a cone with a plane is a parabola is the existence of a generatrix (aka "generating line") of the cone parallel to the section plane.

Let $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ be the coordinates of the apex of the cone.

The problem being symmetrical with respect to plane $z=0$, we can assume $z_1>0$.

- if $z_1=c$, the horizontal line with equations $x_1y=y_1x, z=z_1$ is "responsible" for a parabolic section.

In the other cases, it is impossible:

- if $z_1>c$, no horizontal generatrix exists: it is evident by projecting the cone onto the vertical plane passing through the origin and the apex of the cone.
- if $0 \le z_1<c$ there are two horizontal generatrices, but projecting them onto the horizontal plane show that they are associated with vertical parabolic sections, not horizontal ones.

Remark 1: Using linear transformation $x=aY,y=bY,z=cZ$, one can convert this issue into the configuration of a cone tangent to the unit sphere $X^2+Y^2+Z^2=1$ which can be simpler conceptually (and technically if one has to do computations).

Remark 2: of course points $(0,0,\pm c)$ aren't part of the locus.